# could not solve this error: mutex in c and the lock problems

Tags: c, linux, locking, mutex

My pthreads program is producing inconsistent results:

1. inf
2. 364.000000
3. 360.017792 (the right sol)

I therefore presume I have a problem with locking, but I cannot figure out where or exactly how I should use a mutex to resolve the problem.

Here is my code:

```
#include <pthread.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/syscall.h>
#include <sched.h>
#define _GNU_SOURCE
#include<math.h>
#include <unistd.h>
pthread_mutex_t mutex;

float B=10;
float C=12;
float D=2;
float E=13;
float F=4;
float G=2;
float X,Y,Z,W,V;
float A;

void *t1(void *param);
void *t2(void *param);
void *t3(void *param);
void *t4(void *param);
void *t5(void *param);


int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{



    int num_of_args ;
    pthread_t tid_1;
        pthread_t tid_2;
        pthread_t tid_3;
    pthread_t tid_4;
    pthread_t tid_5;

    pthread_mutex_init(&mutex,NULL);

    pthread_create(&tid_1, NULL, t1, NULL);
    pthread_create(&tid_2, NULL, t2, NULL);
    pthread_create(&tid_3, NULL, t3, NULL);
    pthread_create(&tid_4, NULL, t4, NULL);
    pthread_create(&tid_5, NULL, t5, NULL);




    pthread_join(tid_1, NULL);
    pthread_join(tid_2, NULL);
    pthread_join(tid_3, NULL);
    pthread_join(tid_4, NULL);
    pthread_join(tid_5, NULL);

    A=X+V;  

    printf("______________________________________________\n");
    printf("THE FINAL RESULT = %f\n",A);
        pthread_mutex_destroy(&mutex);

    return(0);
}

void *t1(void *param)
{       
        pthread_mutex_lock(&mutex);

    printf("first Thread\n");
    X=3*B*C;
    printf("the result in this thread : %f\n\n",X);

    pthread_mutex_unlock(&mutex);

    pthread_exit(NULL);
}
void *t2(void *param)
{       
        pthread_mutex_lock(&mutex);

    printf("sec Thread\n");
        Y=D+E;          
    printf("the result in this thread : %f\n\n",Y);

    pthread_mutex_unlock(&mutex);

    pthread_exit(NULL);
}
void *t3(void *param)
{       
        pthread_mutex_lock(&mutex);

    printf("third Thread\n");
        Z=F-G;
    printf("the result in this thread : %f\n\n",Z);

    pthread_mutex_unlock(&mutex);

    pthread_exit(NULL);
}
void *t4(void *param)
{       
    pthread_mutex_lock(&mutex);

    printf("fourth Thread\n");
        W=pow(Y,Z);
    printf("the result in this thread : %f\n\n",W);

    pthread_mutex_unlock(&mutex);

    pthread_exit(NULL);
}
void *t5(void *param)
{              
    pthread_mutex_lock(&mutex);

    printf("fifth Thread\n");
        V=4/W;
    printf("the result in this thread : %f\n\n",V);

    pthread_mutex_unlock(&mutex);

    pthread_exit(NULL);
}
```

How do I need to change this to ensure a consistently correct result?

Comment: my first guess is a dependency problem, not a mutex problem. When you create the threads, you have no idea what order they will be executed in. For example, I see the fourth thread does `W=pow(Y,Z);` and the second thread does `Y=D+E;`. `Y` is uninitialized, so if the fourth thread executes first you have undefined behavior. I'm guessing a closer examination would reveal similar such problems. Also not sure from your question which results apply to which threads.

Comment: If the threads need to be executed one at a time in a particular order, you shouldn't be using threads.

Comment: and just in general, this is a terrible use case for threads. Each one tries to acquire a mutex as soon as it runs, does work in a critical section, then finishes. There is no parallelism at all here, and I would bet this runs slower than a single-threaded app due to spinup time for the threads. If you're simply looking for proof-of-concept thread example, there are far better scenarios than this.

Comment: @yano whether the program's behavior is defined does not depend on the order in which the threads run, nor indeed on anything about any particular execution of the program.  It contains data races, and that is enough for UB in and of itself.

Answer (score 1):

As you can see from the output of the program the situations in which the result differ are when the threads executed in the order you probably did not expect them to.
For example

```
first Thread
the result in this thread : 360.000000

sec Thread
the result in this thread : 15.000000

third Thread
the result in this thread : 2.000000

fourth Thread
the result in this thread : 225.000000

fifth Thread
the result in this thread : 0.017778

______________________________________________
THE FINAL RESULT = 360.017792
```

In this case all threads executed in expected order and the result is good.

On the other hand , here they did not and result is bad :

```
first Thread
the result in this thread : 360.000000

sec Thread
the result in this thread : 15.000000

fifth Thread
the result in this thread : inf

third Thread
the result in this thread : 2.000000

fourth Thread
the result in this thread : 225.000000

______________________________________________
THE FINAL RESULT = inf
```

The truth is, generally you cannot predict which thread will be next to lock the given mutex. Furthermore in this situation the threads are just useless, because threads are used in order to do some work "simultaneously", but here they do not. You could just run the functions one after another from `main()` function

Answer (score 0):

i have solved it and it was pretty easy

```
#include <pthread.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/syscall.h>
#include <sched.h>
#define _GNU_SOURCE
#include<math.h>
#include <unistd.h>
pthread_mutex_t mutex;

float B=10;
float C=12;
float D=2;
float E=13;
float F=4;
float G=2;
float X,Y,Z,W,V;
float A;
// author Hazem Galal
void *t1(void *param);
void *t2(void *param);
void *t3(void *param);
void *t4(void *param);
void *t5(void *param);


int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{



    int num_of_args ;
    pthread_t tid_1;
        pthread_t tid_2;
        pthread_t tid_3;
    pthread_t tid_4;
    pthread_t tid_5;

    pthread_mutex_init(&mutex,NULL);
    pthread_mutex_lock(&mutex);
    pthread_create(&tid_1, NULL, t1, NULL);
    pthread_mutex_lock(&mutex);
    pthread_create(&tid_2, NULL, t2, NULL);
    pthread_mutex_lock(&mutex);
    pthread_create(&tid_3, NULL, t3, NULL);
    pthread_mutex_lock(&mutex);
    pthread_create(&tid_4, NULL, t4, NULL);
    pthread_mutex_lock(&mutex);
    pthread_create(&tid_5, NULL, t5, NULL);




    pthread_join(tid_1, NULL);
    pthread_join(tid_2, NULL);
    pthread_join(tid_3, NULL);
    pthread_join(tid_4, NULL);
    pthread_join(tid_5, NULL);

    A=X+V;  

    printf("______________________________________________\n");
    printf("THE FINAL RESULT = %f\n",A);
        pthread_mutex_destroy(&mutex);

    return(0);
}

void *t1(void *param)
{       


    printf("first Thread\n");
    X=3*B*C;
    printf("the result in this thread : %f\n\n",X);

    pthread_mutex_unlock(&mutex);

    pthread_exit(NULL);
}
void *t2(void *param)
{       


    printf("sec Thread\n");
        Y=D+E;          
    printf("the result in this thread : %f\n\n",Y);

    pthread_mutex_unlock(&mutex);

    pthread_exit(NULL);
}
void *t3(void *param)
{       


    printf("third Thread\n");
        Z=F-G;
    printf("the result in this thread : %f\n\n",Z);

    pthread_mutex_unlock(&mutex);

    pthread_exit(NULL);
}
void *t4(void *param)
{       


    printf("fourth Thread\n");
        W=pow(Y,Z);
    printf("the result in this thread : %f\n\n",W);

    pthread_mutex_unlock(&mutex);

    pthread_exit(NULL);
}
void *t5(void *param)
{              


    printf("fifth Thread\n");
        V=4/W;
    printf("the result in this thread : %f\n\n",V);

    pthread_mutex_unlock(&mutex);

    pthread_exit(NULL);
}
```